# Opening Mongod within python, how to avoid `shell=True`

Tags: python, mongodb, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to write a python script that will start mongod, create a database (or open a database I've already made), add some information, and then shut down mongod.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pymongo import MongoClient
import subprocess

def create_mongo_database(database_name, path_to_database):
    mongod = subprocess.Popen(
        "mongod --dbpath {0}".format(path_to_database),
        shell=True
    )
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client[database_name]
    collection = db['test_collection']
    collection.insert_one({'something new':'some data'})
    mongod.terminate()
```

This code works, but reading the python docs, they say using `shell=True` in subprocess is a bad idea. I'm pretty novice with this stuff, and I don't really understand what the `shell=True` flag is doing,  but I understand that having access to the shell when the input is variable is bad. The problem is, when I try to run this removing the `shell=True` argument, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/KBLaptop/computation/kvasir/mongo_test2.py", line 23, in <module>
    create_mongo_database('test5_database', '~/computation/db')
  File "/Users/KBLaptop/computation/kvasir/mongo_test2.py", line 12, in create_mongo_database
    "mongod --dbpath {0}".format(path_to_database),
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Not sure if it matters, but in both the working case and failing case, I'm running this with `create_mongo_database('test5_database', '~/computation/db')` at the end of the script in sublime text3.

So my questions are - is using `shell=True` dangerous in this case? Why won't the program run if I don't do `shell=True`?

EDIT: Given Dano's and Charles Duffy's explanations, I've now changed the command to:

```
mongod = subprocess.Popen(
    ["mongod", "--dbpath", path_to_database],
)
```

However, this still doesn't work if `path_to_database` contains `~/`. In other words, `/Users/myusername/path/to/db` works, but `~/path/to/db` does not. My initial question is well answered, and I can definitely make this work, not sure if this new wrinkle should be made a new question or not...

Comment: Thought experiment: What happens if your database is in a directory named `"/computation/$(rm -rf .)/db"`?

Comment: I presume I'd have nothing left on my hard drive? That would be fun...

Comment: Yup (worst-case, depending on the details)! But it's the shell invoked by `shell=True` that actually honors that expansion; if there's no shell, then the name is just treated as a literal filename.

Comment: Re: your expansion on the question, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser; I've also expanded my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use `shell=True`, you need to split the command into its individual arguments. The easiest way to do that is with [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
 mongod = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split("mongod --dbpath {0}".format(os.path.expanduser(path_to_database)))
    )
```

**Edit:** Charles Duffy points out that using `shlex.split` in this case will not behave properly for all possible paths. It's better to just explicitly pass an array with `shell=False`. See his answer for more info.

The `shell=True` command tells Python to execute your command using an underlying command prompt (e.g. bash, sh, etc). The reason `shell=True` is considered dangerous is because if you're passing a user-defined string into the command, they could potentially craft a command that will execute arbitrary code. So, in your example, if `path_to_database` is supplied by the user, imagine if they passed this: `"; ls /"`. When you execute the command in the shell, the `;` character is treated like a command separator, and you end up executing `ls /` in addition to the `mongod` command. Obviously, this is very bad.

If you use `shell=False` instead, then the `; ls /` characters will just be treated as arguments to the `mongod` command, rather than be passed to a shell, where the `;` has special meaning.

All that said, if `path_to_database` is not, and never will be, provided by a user, it should be safe to use `shell=True`, but in general it's a good idea to to only use it if you really need to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, you're right. I'll leave my answer for the explanation about the differences between `shell=True` and `shell=False`, but using an explicit array is definitely better than `shlex.split` in this case.

Comment: I agree -- the explanation is useful; as edited, this has my upvote.

Comment: @dano This is super clear, thanks for the explanation! But there's a new wrinkle - please see my edit. Not sure if I should make a new question or not...

Comment: @kevbonham Use [`os.path.expanduser(path_to_database)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to handle the `"~"`.

Answer (score 6):

I actually disagree rather strongly with the existing answer (suggesting `shlex.split()`). That makes sense if you have a shell-quoted string passed in that may contain an unknown number of arguments -- but in this case, you know *exactly* how many arguments you want: You want three, never more or less, and you want to be certain that `path_to_database` becomes only one argument.

Thus, the appropriate thing to use (if one wants tilde-expansion behavior) is:

```
mongod = subprocess.Popen(['mongod', '--dbpath', os.path.expanduser(path_to_database)])
```

Otherwise, a path including spaces will be split into multiple arguments, and a path containing literal quotes (they're legal on UNIX) will have those quotes treated as escaping/syntax rather than data. Using `shell=True` would do both these things and more -- making `shlex.split()` with the default `shell=False` certainly safer -- but passing an explicit array is better still.

Comment: Sucks, I can't mark both explanations as answering... I think reading both (and your hypothetical) helped me understand. There's a new wrinkle though - please take a look at my edit.